# s3 AWS cli deploy only new files command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I currently have a working site, and we are constantly making changes to it. I was wondering if there was a way to make the ./deploy script only deploy new changes, instead of deploying the whole site every time.

MY script is currently this.

```
aws s3 cp _site s3:/fake bucket name/ --recursive --region "ap-southeast-2"
```

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/customerapps/1771

Answer (score 8):

Please take a look at aws cli command: `s3 sync`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

`aws s3 sync _site s3://fake/ --region "ap-southeast-2"`

First try it with `--dryrun` and if it suits your need just remove it.

Comment: Right command is - `aws s3 sync /local/dir/ s3://bucket-name/s3/dir/`. For dry run, it will be `--dryrun` argument.